# Spring controller does not do anything when changing request mapping from GET to POST

Tags: angular, spring

I am trying to send a POST request via JS to Java, but when I make the call the controller does not appear to receive the request, however, when I just change it to a GET request, it works for some reason.

I am not very experienced in JS so I am probably missing something trivial here or something...

JS

```
$rootScope.addItemValue = function(itemValue) {
            $http.get('/addItemValue', { // nothing happens when I change 'get' to 'post'
                params: {
                    item_value: itemValue
                }
            }).then(function(result) {
            });
        };
```

Controller

```
//@PostMapping("/addItemValue") nothing happens when I use this
@GetMapping("/addItemValue")
public void addItem(@RequestParam Integer item_value) {
    System.out.println("value: " + item_value);
}
```

**Update**:

Tried the following, but still not receiving anything in the controller.

index.html

```
<div>
    <h4>Add item value</h4>
    <div>
        Item Value: <input ng-model="itemValue"/>
        <button ng-click="addItem(itemValue)">Add item value</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .run(function($rootScope, $http) {

        $rootScope.addItemValue = function(itemValue) {
            $http.post("/addItemValue", {"item_value": itemValue})
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    console.log(res);
                },
                (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    console.log(err.error);
                    console.log(err.name);
                    console.log(err.message);
                    console.log(err.status);
                }
            );
        };

    });
```

Java controller

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App {

    @PostMapping("/addItemValue")
    public void addTournament(@RequestParam Integer item_value) {
        System.out.println("itemValue: " + item_value);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To properly use Spring and Angular, check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

```
$http.post("/addItemValue", itemValue)
    .subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err.error);
            console.log(err.name);
            console.log(err.message);
            console.log(err.status);
        }
    );
```

**Edit**

Add `@CrossOrigin` and change `@RequestParam` to `@RequestBody` also remove the `{ }` as it will try to be deserialized (Check updated data param above, just plain value `itemValue`)

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App {

    @PostMapping("/addItemValue")
    public void addTournament(@RequestBody Integer item_value) {
        System.out.println("itemValue: " + item_value);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but after replacing the entire http.get method with your post method, I still don't see the print statement...

$rootScope.addItem = function(itemValue) {
         $http.post(
              '/addItemValue', 
              { item_value: itemValue },
              function(data, status){
                  alert(status);
              }
          );
        };

Comment: sorry, I feel incredibly stupid, but I have tried your updated answer (also tried it without item_value in quotes), but I still can't get it to work. I have posted the changes.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately. I should also note that with previous update, the UI isnt appearing correctly, e.g. is is displaying the actual element names for some reason, and if I revert the changes to the original way, the UI issues are gone.

Comment: @mrnoobynoob, please check the changes

Comment: Thanks, but still no changes in functionality. I'll see if I can rewrite this another way from scratch maybe..